# Impossible to reach website from my local network

Tags: ip, wordpress, local-area-network, website, ip-blocking

My company website is hosted on Simply Transit, running WP.

It works perfectly from anywhere outside my company LAN.
Inside the LAN, trying to connect to mycompany.com would result an

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Inside the LAN I can tracert the site and it resolves correctly.
Using a web proxy I can access the site.

I tried to flush dns and disabling firewall on LM, disabling the most 'suspected' WP plugins on server with no results.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: As gerald schneider already commented, this looks like a firewall rule blocking your http/https request to your companys site. Can be your companies firewall or at the server hosting your companies site.

Comment: You can use `tcptraceroute simplytransit.com 443` or something from inside your company’s local network.  The end result of a success will quickly confirm a firewall issue or not.